# Limit Character count in c# String

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code, is there an easy way to limit the amount of characters displayed to 250?

```
<%# trimIt(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "WebSalesText").ToString())%>

public string trimIt(string s)
{
    if (s.Length > 0 && s.IndexOf(".") > 0)
    {
        return (s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(".")) + " ...");
    }
    else
    {
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the `trimIt()` function look like?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Are you looking for an implementation of trimIt?

```
public static string trimIt(string s)
{
   if(s == null)
       return string.Empty;

   int count = Math.Min(s.Length, 250);
   return s.Substring(0, count);
}
```

Comment: +1 _This_ is the correct answer.  This is the only answer that will work reliably and won't be brittle.

Comment: Not sure how smart is Substring about making copies. Wouldn't something like "if (s.Length <= 250) return s; else return s.Substring(0, 250);" be better?

Comment: @Filip: probably not that important but surely a reasonable change.

Comment: Dissasemble System.String using reflector, check InternalSubstring(int, int, bool)... Theres a check for length == this.Length, which will return "this"...

Comment: I use the same code in a Max(int) function that is an extension. This makes for a good extension

Answer (score 8):

You could make an extension method for string to doing what you need and allow you to specify the amount to allow to be the maximum length.

```
public static string TrimToMaxSize(this string input, int max)
{
   return ((input != null) && (input.Length > max)) ?
       input.Substring(0, max) : input;
}
```

Comment: Yes Shorten or something else I am sure might be a better name.  I just came up with the first thing off the top of my head :)

Answer (score 0):

We can use below methods,

> ```
>     public static string RTrim(this string s, int Length)
>     {
>         if (s == null)
>             return string.Empty;
>         return s.Substring(0, s.Length - Length);
>     }
> ```

AND

> ```
>     public static string LTrim(this string s, int Length)
>     {
>         if (s == null)
>             return string.Empty;
>         if (s.Length >= Length)
>         {
>             return s.Substring(0, Length);
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             return s;
>         }
>     }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

This does not work, as SubString will fail for a string shorter than 250 signs.:

```
<%# trimIt(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "WebSalesText").ToString().SubString(0,250))%>
```

but this (dirty) solution would work:

```
<%# trimIt(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "WebSalesText").ToString().
    SubString(0,Math.min(250,
    DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "WebSalesText").ToString().Length))
%>
```

Comment: Might just be me, but won't this fail if the string is less than 250 characters long?

Comment: @LorenVS - you are correct.  This will throw an exception if the string is too short.

Comment: You are right. Never thought that this would fail. Again I see that testing before posting is a good idea.

Comment: somestring.Substring(0, Math.Min(250, entityName.ToString().Length)) works correctly for me. Well, I think it should stay as a bad example - if someone else tries do make this error.